# Create a mysql routine cursor with a select in a select

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I have a table like the following:

```
id  gnome   dead
-----------------
1    pet    yes 
2    pet    no
3    pet    no
4    kin    no
5    kin    yes
6    kin    no
```

Now, I'd like to create a cursor in a routine taking:

1) all the rows where "dead" is "yes";

2) rows where "dead" is "no" only if there are no "dead" = "yes" for the same "gnome" before.

The result should be:

```
id  gnome   dead
-----------------
1    pet    yes 
4    kin    no
5    kin    yes
```

Comment: And you specifically want to engage with cursors for this?

Comment: Where is the code you have done so far?

Comment: @WorkSmarter just pasted the fiddle i was working on. i suppose if that works in a select, it should work for a cursor aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution does not appear to fit your requirement. Here's a solution that does:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE dead = 'yes'
 UNION
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.gnome = x.gnome 
   AND y.dead = 'yes' 
   AND y.id < x.id 
 WHERE x.dead = 'no'
   AND y.id IS NULL;
```

As regards the difference between your query and mine, consider the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+-------+------+
| id | gnome | dead |
+----+-------+------+
|  1 | pet   | yes  |
|  2 | pet   | no   |
|  3 | pet   | no   |
|  4 | kin   | no   |
|  5 | kin   | yes  |
|  6 | kin   | no   |
|  7 | cat   | no   |
|  8 | cat   | yes  |
|  9 | uno   | no   |
| 10 | uyes  | yes  |
+----+-------+------+
```

Do you want row 9 returned or not?

Comment: cool, thanks... i think i just need to order by id and it should be perfect. Would you explain where is my solution going to fail? just to better understand

Comment: You wanted one thing OR the other thing. Your query appears to return BOTH. A more representative data set might illustrate the problem better.

Comment: mmm still didn't get it, would you show in which case would it fail? anyway i will use your solution! thanks

Comment: in your edit, i need rows 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10 and both solutions looks to return the same

Comment: Well, pehaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: anyway, your solution looks faster on a big table (200k+ rows), so i will go for it! thanks again

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think i found a solution

```
SELECT * FROM asd AS t WHERE dead = 'yes' OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT k.dead FROM asd as k WHERE k.id < t.id AND t.gnome = k.gnome and k.dead = 'yes')
```

i created a fiddle here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc0cd/8/0

What do You think? Should it be ok in a routine cursor?